# Connecting to local database via SharePoint Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql-server

Following [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-database-as-a-data-source-3a563b0c-75e4-4856-847f-9a8182708c66) I am trying to connect to a local SQL database using SharePoint Designer.
I am able to create external content type, use it in external list, and the list is correctly populated with data from the database:
[image]

However, when I try to connect to database using connection string, it returns an error:
[image]

The connection strings I tried (from various sources and articles):

- Data Source=win\SharePoint;Initial Catalog=Testing1;User Id=Administrator;Password=AuthenticPassword;
- Data Source='(local)';Initial Catalog=Testing1;User Id=Administrator;Password=AuthenticPassword;
- Data Source='(local)';Initial Catalog=Testing1;User Id=user1PresentInSecurityLoginsinSQLdatabase;Password=AuthenticPassword;
- Server=win\SharePoint;Database=Testing1;User Id=user1;
  Password=AuthenticPassword;
- Server='(local)';Database=Testing1;User Id=user1;
  Password=AuthenticPassword;

The error is still the same. Since the external CT can be created without issues, the database is not an issue. What am I doing wrong with the connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filling the information in **Connect to a Data Server** dialog instead of **Use Custom Connection string** as you might face an error while giving the details of the connection string. Let it create the connection string by its own by the parameters you pass in dialog fields. As i can see that all the connection strings are correct but If you still get an error than you can follow steps mentioned in below given link.

[Step by Step Part 2: Creating the External Content Type](http://sharepoint-blog.com/business-connectivity-services-bcs-overview/)

**Some Workaround for your Error**

> There are several solutions out there in the web for this error like
>   the ones listed below but none of them are sure shot fixes
>
> [How to fix: Recieve error "Unable to display this Web Part" on Data
>   Views after restoring site from backup](http://blogs.msdn.com/spdsupport/archive/2008/06/06/how-to-fix-error-unable-to-display-this-web-part-on-data-views-after-restoring-site-from-backup.aspx)
>
> After having tried out several solutions with no luck we tried copy
>   the datasource from a newly created dataview and replace the
>   datasource in the erroneous dataview. Gotcha this worked.  Below are
>   the steps we did
>
> 1. Create a new page in SharePoint designer.
> 2. Add a dataview webpart to the new page and set the datasource as the same list or library that the erroneous dataview uses.
> 3. Switch to the code view.
> 4. Open the page with the erroneous dataview in code view mode.
> 5. Copy the datasource element from the dataview in new page
> 6. Replace the datasource element of the erroneous dataview with the copied datasource element

Comment: the article explains how to create the external content type. In my case it works perfectly (and the external data source IS discovered without issues). Only when I go to Data Sources (on the left)>Database Connection>Configure Database Connection, I receive the errors. It does not matter whether I fill the data in the fields or whether I enter them as a connection string.

Comment: Is there any specific requirement to connect it again after creating External content type?

Comment: You can use Secure Store service to get it connected as many times you need. as it saves the connection in it.

Comment: Kindly Check here...https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-an-External-List-from-a-SQL-Azure-table-with-Business-Connectivity-Services-and-Secure-Store-466f3809-fde7-41f2-87f7-77d9fdadfc95

Comment: Please check updated answer.

Comment: Check here as well...http://itgroove.net/brainlitter/2008/08/06/sharepoint-server-returned-non-specific-error-when-trying-to-get-data-from-the-data-source/

Comment: Thank you, Hardik, for so much info. About the requirements: I need connection string for a more complex database, but wanted to start with something simple that will surely work :D  About the last link: The table contains only 3 sample columns and the same table/database connects without issues via external content type. I'll check the rest.

Comment: Ok sure..Please let me know if you need some more help in it..

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: No :( The DataView webpart shows EMPTY <DataSource> (I used the correct list). Secure Store is not an option (SPFoundation) - I'll check it out later just for myself. I also tried third party - http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/products/Pages/SharePoint-Business-Data-List-Connector.aspx, but it fails again at the validation of the connection string. Maybe it's the users I created. Do you know what requirements/permissions they have to fulfill?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40891/discussion-between-hardik-and-grisha).